# how to mock an imported class in my script from a jest test

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mocking

in one of my constructors, i instantiate another class, however to test in isolation, i need to mock the implementation of the other class constructor. i have tried several approaches, but have been unable to accomplish this.

the example below obviously doesn't work, since it isn't mocking the import from `foo.js`, but hopefully it shows what i am trying to do

./foo.js

```js
import Bar from './bar.js'

export default class Foo {
  bar: undefined

  constructor() {
    this.bar = new Bar
  }
}
```

./bar.js

```js
export default class Bar {
  constructor() {
    console.log('i do not want this to run')
  }  
}
```

./foo.test.js

```js
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

jest.mock('./bar.js', () => {
  class BarMock {
    constructor() {
      console.log('i want this to run')
    }  
  }
})

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('should...', () => {
    const foo = new Foo

    expect(foo.bar).toBeInstanceOf(BarMock)
    expect(Bar).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```js
jest.mock('./bar.js')
```

and in case you want the mock to call `console.log` within the constructor add:

```js
Bar.prototype.constructor.mockImplementation(() => {
  console.log('i want this to run')
})
```

**Edit:** here's an example

**`foo.test.js`**

```js
import Foo from "./foo.js";
import Bar from "./bar.js";

jest.mock("./bar.js");

Bar.prototype.constructor.mockImplementation(() => {
  console.log("i want this to run");
});

describe("Foo", () => {
  it("should...", () => {
    const foo = new Foo();

    expect(foo.bar).toBeInstanceOf(Bar);
    expect(Bar).toBeCalled();
  });

  it("should be a mock function", () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(Bar)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

[working setup](https://github.com/Teneff/mocking-bar)

Comment: this doesn't seem to mock the Bar class when it's run in `foo.js`, only for the Bar class in `foo.test.js`.  even though i mock it from my test, when `new Bar` is run in my script, it's the actual Bar class, not the mocked one

Comment: wow thank you for creating that repo! and it definitely works... however my implementation does not. but now that i know the correct approach and know it works, i can better troubleshoot.  this repo is helping me play around with a working example, that i can slowly modify it to be closer to my actual code.  i thought my contrived example was an accurate representation of my code, but apparently not

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this code below is what you need,

but the following code called the mocked console.log when I run the test

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

jest.mock('./bar.js')

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('should...', () => {
    Bar.prototype.constructor.mockImplementation(() => {
      console.log('i want this to run')
    })

    const foo = new Foo

    expect(foo.bar).toBeInstanceOf(Bar);
    expect(Bar).toBeCalled()
  })
})
```

this is the result [image]