# Trying to mock cognitoUser.authenticateUser from amazon-cognito-identity-js and getting that it's undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amazon-cognito, create-react-app

I am trying to write some unit tests in Jest for a Create React App project I have which uses Amazon Cognito.

The code under test:

```
const getNewCognitoUser = (username) => {
    const userData = {
        Username: username,
        Pool: userPool,
    };
    return new CognitoUser(userData);
};

const setAWSCredentials = (jwt) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: appConfig.IdentityPoolId,
            Logins: {
                [appConfig.Logins.cognito.identityProviderName]: jwt,
            },
        });
        AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId();
        AWS.config.credentials.refresh((err) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve();
        });
    });
};

export const authenticate = (username, password) => {
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    });

    cognitoUser = getNewCognitoUser(username);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                setAWSCredentials(result.idToken.jwtToken)
                    .then(() => {
                        resolve(result);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    });
            },
            onFailure: function (err) {
                reject(err);
            },
            newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
                reject({
                    code: "PasswordResetRequiredException",
                    message: "New Password Required",
                    newPasswordRequired: true,
                });
            },
        });
    });
};
```

The test

```
import { authenticate } from "../user";
import { CognitoUser } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

jest.mock("amazon-cognito-identity-js", () => {
    const mCognitoUser = {
        authenticateUser: jest.fn((authenticationDetails, callbacks) => {
            if (callbacks && callbacks.onSuccess) {
                // Simulate a successful authentication

                callbacks.onSuccess({ idToken: { jwtToken: "fakeToken" } });
            }
        }),
    };

    return {
        CognitoUser: jest.fn(() => mCognitoUser),

        CognitoUserPool: jest.fn(),

        AuthenticationDetails: jest.fn(),

        CognitoUserAttribute: jest.fn(),
    };
});

jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
    const mCognitoIdentityCredentials = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            clearCachedId: jest.fn(),

            refresh: jest.fn(),
        };
    });

    return {
        CognitoIdentityCredentials: mCognitoIdentityCredentials,
        config: {},
    };
});

describe("do I understand mocks", () => {
    test("let's find out", async () => {
        console.log(CognitoUser);
        const mCognitoUser = new CognitoUser();
        console.log(mCognitoUser);
        console.log(mCognitoUser.authenticateUser);

        await authenticate("foo", "bar");
        expect(CognitoUser.authenticate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

This tells me that the function authenticateUser is undefined and of course it fails when trying to run

```
await authenticate("foo", "bar")
```

stating that

```
TypeError: cognitoUser.authenticateUser is not a function
```

AFAICT, the code is properly mocked, so why doesn't it see that there is a mock implementation for authenticateUser?

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567956/how-to-mock-an-imported-class-in-my-script-from-a-jest-test), which is for a similar issue, but adding the modules to a new create-react-app project didn't cause them to print the expected output (or anything at all for that matter), although downloading the github link provided in the post did work.  No idea what the difference is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

The app was generated using Create React App and the default setting for resetMocks is true, which has the effect of blowing away the mock implementations I set up.  I am not sure why that's the default, but adding the following to my package.json file solved the problem.

```
    "jest": {
        "resetMocks": false
    }
```